# Django - finding the module where warnings are coming from?

Tags: django, django-testing, django-manage.py

Here's my test output. I can't figure out where the bad DateTimeField is being set, because all I can see is: /home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py

which isn't very useful at narrowing the problem. How do I get more details on what's causing the warnings? A stacktrace would be nice!

Thanks for any help!

```
python -W manage.py test

Creating test database for alias 'default'...
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................./home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/defaults.py:3: PendingDeprecationWarning: django.conf.urls.defaults is deprecated; use django.conf.urls instead
  PendingDeprecationWarning)
/home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-02-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-02-01 23:59:59.999999) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:761: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-01-31 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:761: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-02-02 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
/home/workspace/ticktockgo/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:761: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-03-01 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
..............ss.s..............................................................................................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 491 tests in 20.825s

OK (skipped=3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace [`warnings.showwarning`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.showwarning) with a function that uses [`traceback`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) to find and display the current stack frame.

Comment: Thanks! Can you suggest a logical place to put the override? manage.py? :\

Comment: @Charled: I would put it in `settings.py`, since that will always be imported.